# Fate/unlimited codes multiplayer

Tags: psp, psn

I was considering getting Fate/unlimited codes off of PSN. I only own a PS3, but I remember hearing that you could play PSP games on your PS3 if gotten through PSN. Since this seems to be a fighting game, would I be able to do multiplayer using the same console with two controllers? That's not normally possible on the PSP, so I believe the answer is probably no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only play Minis and PS1 classics on both PSP and PS3. Regular PSP games such as Fate/unlimited Codes are not playable on PS3.